# How to delete return value if variable is blank in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have written one function :

```
function abcd(gg,hh,ii,jj){
return "Hi,\n\nBelow is alert."\n\n"+gg+"\n"+hh+"\n"+ii+"\n"+jj+";
}
```

where 4 variables gg,hh,ii,jj has written globally and calling dynamically. where 'gg' containg 'Approval is done', 'hh' containg 'Approval is done', 'ii' containg 'Approval is done', 'jj' containg 'Approval is done'. My concern is sometime i have value for gg , hh, ii or jj and sometime not and i am getting output as below if i have value for all variable by mentioned above Function code:

```
Hi,

Below is alert.

Approval is done.
Approval is done.
Approval is done.
Approval is done.
```

So If 'ii' is blank then i need as below, but my code is returning line space if 'ii' is blank:

```
Hi,

Below is alert.

Approval is done.
Approval is done.
Approval is done.
```

Comment: `[gg,hh,ii,jj].filter(Boolean).join("\n")`

Comment: Can you please fix that string literal?

Comment: Just don't include that part if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the cleanest, with how you have it, would be something like this:

```
function abcd(gg,hh,ii,jj){
    return "Hi,\n\nBelow is alert.\n\n" 
        + (gg ? gg + "\n" : '')
        + (hh ? hh + "\n" : '')
        + (ii ? ii + "\n" : '')
        + jj;
}
```

The ternary operator (`?:`) is in the format `condition ? if_true : if_false`. You can check for a "falsy" value on the string (`null` and `''` both count as false), so it'll only output stuff if it's not falsey.

Answer (score 2):

If ii will be an **empty string**, here is a quick fix:

```
function abcd(gg,hh,ii,jj){
return "Hi,\n\nBelow is alert.\n\n" + [gg,hh,ii,jj].filter(Boolean).join("\n");
}
```

`.filter(Boolean)` basicaly filters empty strings, (since those will return `false`, which is a `boolean`).

`.join("\n")` converts your array to a `string`, But with using `\n` rather than `,`

Comment: I actually like your solution a bit better than my own.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.filter` to filter out the blank ones, and then join them:

```
function getNonBlanks(array) {
    return array.filter(function (i) {
        // we only want items with a length
        return i.length > 0;
    });
}

function abcd(gg,hh,ii,jj){
    return "Hi,\n\nBelow is alert.\n\n" + getNonBlanks([gg,hh,ii,jj]).join("\n");
}
```